# undefined method `write_reviews' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0xaadd320>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi i am having two tables named users and write_reviews ,i have created active association between them as user has_many write_reviews while write_reviews belongs_to user 
in my method i am trying to do like this

```
def details
    @user = User.all
    @writereview  = @user.write_reviews.all
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @writereview }
  end
```

in my write_review model it is defined like

```
class WriteReview < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

but it is giving error

Comment: Where is it giving you the error? show that part of the code please. You have to call `write_reviews` on a `User` object, you can't do it on a `ActiveRecordRelation`. That's why you getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

`User.all` returns array(`ActiveRecord::Relation`) that all users.

write_reviews relation is associated with single user instance.

user has many wirte_reviews, not users(User.all)

`@user` must be one User instance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `write_reviews` on a `User` object, you can't do it on a `ActiveRecordRelation`. That's why you getting that error. You can do these instead:

```
@user = User.first # or something else that returns a single user
@writereview  = @user.write_reviews.all
```

Comment: Thanks for reply ...I want to show all reviews and their user details

Comment: So, then, in your view, you can loop through all the reviews and show them and also their corresponding user data.

Comment: i m using json file and angular js to get the data to view but in my json file i am getting only reviews records.

Answer (score 0):

> undefined method `write_reviews' for User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0xaadd320

The error is due to this line

```
@writereview  = @user.write_reviews.all
```

Here `@user` is a ***collection*** of users records according to your code, so `@user.write_reviews` is wrong.

If you want get the `write_reviews` of a particular user, then you need to change `@user = User.all` to `@user = User.find(params[:id])`

Comment: I want writereviews for all users

Comment: If he is in the  writereviews controller _User.find(params[:id])_ wont work, instead you have to write _User.find(params[:user_id])_

Answer (score 0):

so to first the code looks like this, in order to retrieve all users writereviews :

```
@users = User.all
```

so now *@users* contains all your users, nothing's complicated here. we re gonna declare a variable *@writereviews* as an *array*.

```
@writereviews = []
@users.each do |u|
 @writereviews << u.writereviews.all
end
```

now, you have all the writereviews of each user. the first element is an array that holds all the *writereviews* of the first user. we'll put it like that

```
@writereviews[0] // is an array containing all the write reviews of your first user.
@writereviews[0][0] // is the nested array containing the FIRST writereview of your
                      FIRST user
@writereviews[0][0].user // will give you the user of that review.
```

so in order to retrieve users of those writereviews,I came with a loop inside an other.

```
@authors = []
@writereviews.each do |element|
 element.each do |subelement|
  @authors << subelement.user
  break // so that it doesnt neet to loop over the other writereviews, since they will all belongs to the same user.
 end
end
```

and thats it, you can use *@authors* to retrieve the users of each writereview, **@authors[0]** is the user of the **@writereviews[0]**, all what you need to do, is use those variables in your template.

Hope this is more clear to you now !

for the json part :

```
@total = [] #each element of this array would contain a hash of _'user, reviews[]'_
wrev = {}  # a hash that will contain the user, and its write reviews
wrev["user"] = ""
wrev["wrev"] = []  #reviews are an array 

@users.each do |u|
 wrev["user"] = u.email
 wrev["wrev"] = []
 wrev["wrev"] = u.writereviews.all
 @total << wrev 
 wrev = {}
end

respond_to do |format|
 format.html
 format.json { render json: @total }
end
```

Comment: Thanks for reply ..yes I want write reviews for every user ..can you please give an example how to loop to get desired result ..

Comment: After that you declared _users = User.all_ below it type :        _users.each do |u|  writereviews << u.writereviews.all end_ so far you have writereviews containing all reviews for every user. Now you can use it in your view to loop over it and display each item on its own with _each method_     PS: add the @ sign before every variable

Comment: thanks i have tried ..def details
   user = User.all
    user.each do |u|
    writereview  = u.write_reviews.all
    end
    
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @writereview }
  end
  end  in my json file it is only showing [{"id":15,"clean":"5","food":"4","locality":"5","behavior":"5","amenity":"4","likes":"food","dislikes":"no amenties","comment":"no comments","created_at":"2015-12-07T06:00:20.000Z","updated_at":"2015-12-07T06:00:20.000Z","user_id":6}]

Comment: Try add : _@writereview.user_ to your render json

Comment: no luck ..showing an error   " undefined method `user' for #<WriteReview::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0xd4581b0>"

Comment: Yeah sorry i forgot that @writereviews is an array itself.

Comment: and even while looping @writereview it is not giving all writereviews value only the last record of table ,is that we need to append values to writereview while looping coz after loop ends i=this variable has only last record.

Comment: Well of course you have to append while looping, thats what i have put in my answer ! You have to use a << sign not = sign

Comment: ya i tried its giving error "undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: Ok give me 5 min, can you try writereviews.push(u.writereviews)

Comment: Ok you just have to define @writereviews as an array _@writereviews = [ ]_ then call the each method afterwards

Comment: thanks it works ,please extend your help for getting users information as well in json file coz in my view i have to show username who posted the reviews

Comment: is there anyother way to append while looping coz the way u suggested changing the json file format .it inserts extra [] to every record row .

Comment: json file is like ..[[{"id":16,"clean":"3","food":"5","locality":"4","behavior":"3","amenity":"1","likes":"wifi","dislikes":"food","comment":"","created_at":"2015-12-08T06:55:30.000Z","updated_at":"2015-12-08T06:55:30.000Z","user_id":2}],[],[{"id":15,"clean":"5","food":"4","locality":"5","behavior":"5","amenity":"4","likes":"food","dislikes":"no amenties","comment":"no comments","created_at":"2015-12-07T06:00:20.000Z","updated_at":"2015-12-07T06:00:20.000Z","user_id":6}]] here in every record row is in [] which is not required .

Comment: Thanks for reply ..but I don't understand how i can a json file which will have users as well as their reviews ..

Comment: thanks for helping me ,now json file is like .[{"user":"Pradeep Yadav","wrev":[{"id":15,"clean":"5","food":"4","locality":"5","behavior":"5","amenity":"4","likes":"food","dislikes":"no amenties","comment":"no comments","created_at":"2015-12-07T06:00:20.000Z","updated_at":"2015-12-07T06:00:20.000Z","user_id":6}]}]
so in view how can i show "likes" node value coz now entire review record is in wrev[{}] and also if i need to show more fields of user model in view

Comment: coz likes node is in wrev[{}], i m not able call as wrev.likes in json file it should be like wrev{"likes":} this extra [] causing the issue .

Answer (score 0):

```
User.all
```

Returns an array of users, while `write_reviews` available only on single user.

Actually, in your case you don't need to select write_reviews by users, instead you can simply do:

```
@write_reviews = WriteReview.all
```

But if you want to select write_reviews only for specific users, you can do it like so:

```
@users = User.where(status: 'active') # just an example
@write_reviews = WriteReview.where(user_id: @users.map(&:id))
```

Comment: Why woule he use a dynamic query to retrieve a specific user's reviews, he has an association between the two models, your answer can be legerely modified to :   _@writereviews = @user.writeeviews.all_  while _@user = User.find(params[:user_id])_ considering he s on the write_reviews controller .

Comment: For example, if he wants to get reviews for many specific users, not one.